# Silverlight XAML - Background property on shell.xaml  - Update background of grid

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm

#### UPDATE

I corrected the problem with the help of the help of the group here and this code is the corrected code for any that may want to use it in the future. Simply post the code in your shellviewmodel and update the ThemeChange sub to reflect the colors you want for your background. This background show a vertical LinearGradient.

To use the EventSystem, please see this post: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/

I am attempting to update the back ground of the entire app. I am using Silverlight 5 + Prism + MEF.

Here is the shell.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Insight.Shell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="1024" d:DesignWidth="768">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Height="Auto" 
    Width="Auto"
    MouseRightButtonDown="LayoutRoot_MouseRightButtonDown"
    Background="{Binding BackGroundBrush}">
    </Grid>
```

Here is the shellViewModel:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Data
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Interop
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands
Imports PrismFramework.Abstractions.Bases
Imports PrismFramework.Abstractions.Interfaces
Imports PrismFramework.Implementors.Commanding
Imports PrismFramework.Implementors.Primitives
Imports PrismFramework.Abstractions.Globalization
Imports PrismFramework.Implementors.Interaction.Request
Imports Insight.ModuleUser.Services
Imports Insight.DataServices.Services
Imports Insight.ModuleUser.Interfaces
Imports Insight.DataServices.Primitives
Imports Insight.Controls.ModalDialogViewModels
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Theming

<Export()> _
<PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)> _
Public Class ShellViewModel
Inherits ViewModelBase
Implements IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification

#Region "Attributes"
Private backgroundDefaultPrimaryColor As Color = New Color With {.A = 128, .R = 128, .G = 128, .B = 128}
Private backgroundDefaultSecondaryColor As Color = New Color With {.A = 222, .R = 222, .G = 222, .B = 222}

Private backgroundPrimaryColor As Color
Private backgroundSecondaryColor As Color

Private backgroundGradientStop1 As GradientStop = New GradientStop() With {.Color = BackgroundDefaultColor, .Offset = "0"}
Private backgroundGradientStop2 As GradientStop = New GradientStop() With {.Color = backgroundPrimaryColor, .Offset = "0.185"}
Private backgroundGradientStop3 As GradientStop = New GradientStop() With {.Color = backgroundSecondaryColor, .Offset = "0.8"}
Private backgroundGradientStop4 As GradientStop = New GradientStop() With {.Color = BackgroundDefaultColor, .Offset = "1"}

Private backgroundGradientStops As GradientStopCollection = New GradientStopCollection From {backgroundGradientStop1, backgroundGradientStop2, backgroundGradientStop3, backgroundGradientStop4}

#End Region
#Region "Instantiators"
<ImportingConstructor()> _
Public Sub New()
    backgroundPrimaryColor = backgroundDefaultPrimaryColor
    backgroundSecondaryColor = backgroundDefaultSecondaryColor
    BackGroundBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(backgroundGradientStops, 90)
End Sub
#End Region
#Region "IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification"
Public Sub OnImportsSatisfied() Implements IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification.OnImportsSatisfied
    ' Subscribe to any MenuClick events
    EventSystem.Subscribe(Of Theme)(AddressOf ThemeChange)
End Sub
#End Region
#Region "ThemeChange"
Public Sub ThemeChange(theme As Theme)
    'Parse out themeName
    Dim sThemeName() As String = theme.ToString.Split(".")
    Select Case sThemeName(UBound(sThemeName))
        Case "BubbleCremeTheme"
            backgroundPrimaryColor = Color.FromArgb(123, 235, 111, 234)
            backgroundSecondaryColor = Color.FromArgb(12, 23, 11, 23)
            Exit Select
        Case "ExpressionDarkTheme"
            backgroundPrimaryColor = New Color With {.A = 222, .R = 222, .G = 222, .B = 222}
            backgroundSecondaryColor = New Color With {.A = 245, .R = 245, .G = 245, .B = 245}
            Exit Select
        Case "ExpressionLightTheme"

            Exit Select
        Case "No Theme"
            Exit Select
        Case "Rainier Orange"

            Exit Select
        Case "Rainier Purple"

            Exit Select
        Case "Shiny Blue"

            Exit Select
        Case "Shiny Red"

            Exit Select
        Case "Twilight Blue"

            Exit Select
        Case Else
            backgroundPrimaryColor = backgroundDefaultPrimaryColor
            backgroundSecondaryColor = backgroundDefaultSecondaryColor
    End Select
    'Setup the gradient stops that changed
    backgroundGradientStop2 = New GradientStop() With {.Color = backgroundPrimaryColor, .Offset = "0.185"}
    backgroundGradientStop3 = New GradientStop() With {.Color = backgroundSecondaryColor, .Offset = "0.8"}
    'Now setup the gradientstop collection and create the brush
    backgroundGradientStops.Clear()
    backgroundGradientStops = New GradientStopCollection From {backgroundGradientStop1, backgroundGradientStop2, backgroundGradientStop3, backgroundGradientStop4}
    BackGroundBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(backgroundGradientStops, 90)
End Sub
#End Region
#Region "BackgroundDefaultColor"
Private _backgroundDefaultColor As Color = New Color() With {.A = 255, .R = 255, .G = 255, .B = 255}
Public Property BackgroundDefaultColor() As Color
    Get
        Return Me._backgroundDefaultColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        If Me._backgroundDefaultColor <> value Then
            Me._backgroundDefaultColor = value
            OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundDefaultColor")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
#End Region
#Region "BackgroundBrush"
Dim _backgroundBrush As Brush
Public Property BackGroundBrush() As Brush
    Get
        Return Me._backgroundBrush
    End Get
    Set(value As Brush)
        If Me._backgroundBrush IsNot value Then
            Me._backgroundBrush = value
            OnPropertyChanged("BackGroundBrush")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
#End Region
End Class
```

As you can see in the constuctor I set up the defaults for the app then update the BackgroundBrush property. The code hits this point, and the Get property is called, but the for some reason the background brush doesn't update on the GUI. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't appear to set any `DataContext` but try to bind to it?

Comment: The binding to the view model happens via MEF. I can set a breakpoint at the BackGroundBrush Setter and the property gets hits and the corresponding get property fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a property Back_**G**_roundBrush that is set in the constructor and the binding works. Then you fire OnPropertyChanged("Back***g***roundBrush") and that is not picked up by the binding mechanism since the name of the property is not right. The binding looks for a capital 'G' and you fire with a lower-case 'g'.

Comment: Thank you so much. I stared at the code for at least an hour or two trying to figure out why it wasn't working. I updated the Original ShellViewModel to reflect the changes I had to make to get it working.